# Change url every 2 seconds in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do a simple program to change between 2 url each 2 seconds. When I click the button i see the first web page, however it don't change the page and it don't print in console what I want to debug and I don't know why.

If you can help me you'll make me a favor.

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<button onclick="Start()">Start script</button>
<head>
    <script>

        function Start() {
          location.replace("https://www.w3schools.com");
          setInterval(myFunction, 2000);
        }
        
        var a = 2;
        console.log(a);
        
        function myFunction() {
            console.log(a);
            if (a == 1){
                location.replace("https://www.youtube.com/");
                a=2;
                setInterval(myFunction, 2000);
        
            }
            else{
                location.replace("https://www.google.com/");
                a=1;
                setInterval(myFunction, 2000);
            }
        
        }
          
        </script>
    
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As soon as you are on Google (or YouTube) your script does not longer exist / run and you cannot change that fact. You may be able to load Google and YouTube in an iFrame and control the source of that iFrame from outside of it or create a browser extension. But a regular JavaScript snippet as you have here will never work.

Comment: @luk2302 that's an valid answer I think

Comment: btw if you implement that script into the webpage you are redirecting to, be warn that you call each 2 second a function that call each 2 second herself and so you are stacking them a lot, you will have some problems.